# How to install python modules in sandstorm.io/ipython app?

Tags: ipython, jupyter, sandstorm.io

I have a self-hosted [sandstorm.io](http://sandstorm.io) instance with the [ipython](http://ipython.org) app installed.

How do I install python modules so that they are accessible from ipython notebooks?

Ipython is packaged in a sandstorm app with pre-installed modules. As apps are in sandboxes, `pip install sympy` is not enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, this currently isn't possible, because inside a Sandstorm container the app code is read-only. To make this work, we'd need to do one of the following:

1. The IPython app could be designed to download and install packages into /var, which is writable but specific to one notebook. This could probably be done with minor app changes only. The down side is that you'd have to re-install modules for each notebook you create, wasting time and storage space. (IPython would also need to explicitly ask permission to talk to the package repository before it could download anything.)
2. Sandstorm could implement a planned feature we call "add-on packages", which would allow defining an SPK (Sandstorm package) which adds files to some other SPK. Then, Python packages would need to be converted to such SPKs (this part could probably be automated). You could then install modules across all your notebooks at once. Unfortunately we aren't sure how soon we'll be able to add this.

Comment: Are there some instructions/examples to use ipython form sandstorm -  like upload data, pictures ... via ssh ... howto share directory with Davros ... what I only see is user vagrant from ipython `%%bash ls -la`

Comment: @jaromrax Currently there's no way to connect ipython to another app like Davros. Both apps would need to be updated to support the Powerbox UI to request and provide external resources.